# android view getParent() method signature

Tags: android, api, view

Why is android view's method `getParent()` returns a `ViewParent` As View would have parent only when it is in `ViewGroup` hence I expect `view.getParent()` always return `ViewGroup` and not `ViewParent`.

Is there any special case `ViewParent` which is not `ViewGroup` can be parent of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for example `ViewRootImpl` is not a `ViewGroup` but implements `ViewParent` ([reference](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java#96)).